How to handle reviews that are not about the content of the submission, but about the expanding the scope?
We recently submitted a paper and received the first round of reviews. For the sake of this question, lets say our paper was "On the bending durability of different types of natural reeds in underwater basket weaving."
While the assessment was generally positive and some of the comments were about the actual content of the paper, quite a few of them were along the lines of:

why did you not also research the influence of water quality?
why did you not also look into the influence of artificial reeds?
why did you not also test for tensile durability, salt water resistance and biodegradability of the reeds?
why did you not test the reeds' applicability for open air lampshade knitting?

I am kind of baffled and confused by this. The only answer I can think of is "We did not do any of these things because the scope and focus of our research was to conduct a study on the bending durability of different types of natural reeds in underwater basket weaving." I don't want to appear rude or unwilling to improve my paper, but honestly, the only way to entertain these requests would be to rerun the entire research which is just not feasible. Especially given the paper is already rather lengthy and were we to rerun the study with all requested features, we could probably fill a small book.
If the reviewers felt the scope is too narrow, they could have voted reject, but instead their general feedback was very positive with high scores for novelty and importance in the field. What is the best course of action / response in this case?

Say what you say here about your focus. Thank the reviewers for suggestions about future work and that you will look in to that as appropriate.
There is nothing really to criticize here. These are thoughts that occurred to the reviewers who considered it worth a few words to pass on to you.
It would only be a problem if you are rejected for lack of impact, which doesn't seem like a possibility here. And, if the reviewers did, indeed, feel that the scope was too narrow, they might well have recommended reject. The fact that they did not, apparently, tells you something.

The best course of action if a reviewer asks a question is to take it at face value and answer it. In your examples, this means you just explain why you did not do the mentioned things. If the reviewers want to be more demanding, they could write that you should do these things, which apparently they did not.

I agree completely with Buffy and Snijderfrey’s answers: these are not suggestions to redo everything, and you shouldn’t treat them as such. But an additional angle that I would consider is that if these additional scopes/aspects came to mind for the reviewers while reading your paper, it is likely they will also spring to future readers’ minds.
As such, it may be beneficial to add a note somewhere in your preamble or introduction, to the effect that other properties of natural reeds and the suitability of artificial reeds are outside the scope of your study, but that you hope you may provide inspiration for other studies to examine these aspects of underwater basket weaving.
This sort of thing is, in essence, quite low-density waffle that doesn’t really affect your paper much – but it can be useful to explicitly acknowledge that you’re aware of such adjacent aspects, to prevent the reader from thinking it’s an oversight that they’re not dealt with.

Preamble or introduction might be fine. Further, it could go into the outlook as future research questions. Maybe for your next application of funding or a master's thesis or somebody else.

@usr1234567 Yes, if there is a dedicated section for that (not common in my field of humanities), that would be an obvious place to put it.

Based on my experience, reviewers who pose these questions aren't thinking of rejecting your paper; they're just wondering about possible extensions.
If you can discuss why the proposed extension does not help, you can do so ("We didn't investigate the water quality because it is not likely to have an impact for so-and-so reasons"); otherwise you can also write "so-and-so is an interesting extension, but beyond the scope of our study". If you can add the relevant text to the paper without disrupting the flow, that would be great; if not, a direct response to the reviewer without making any changes is still usually OK.

I have seen properly negative reviews for the only reason that the authors didn't do some additional stuff the reviewer thought should be done on top of what was already there and more or less fine. However in such cases there is a good chance that the editor who ultimately makes the decision would accept a response as outlined in the answers here, even if the reviewer doesn't.
